# How to assign values to the parameters of <portlet:resourceURL/>?

Tags: jsp, jboss, jstl, portlet, jboss-portal

I'm trying to assign values to the parameters of <portlet:resourceURL/>

```
<portlet:resourceURL id="<%=Constants.Color%>" var="<%=Constants.Color%>"/>
```

This code does not work.

```
public class Constants {
    public static final String Color = "Red";
}
```

Comment: If the Constants is the model object that pass to the view, try using `<portlet:resourceURL id="${constants.Color}" var="${constants.Color}"/>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to pass param using resourceURL from your jsp you will do something like...

```
      <portlet:resourceURL var="varname" escapeXml="false">
        <portlet:param name="paramName" value="paramVal" />
      </portlet:resourceURL>
```

In your portlet

```
      request.getParameter("paramName");
```